# URLFetchApp with certificate: Google scripts with Apple ads reporting API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Hi I'm attempting to pull data from the Apple Ads API into a Google sheet, and I'm getting completely stuck on providing the security certificates.  I've  been able to successfully pull my data using Postman, so I'm comfortable that I can structure the request properly.

I'm trying to use URLFetchApp, but I can't see any means of including the PEM and KEY file, or even using the curl example provided by Apple of combining to the P12 file.  Am I missing something here or is URLFetchApp unable to complete this?

It doesn't appear to me that this would fit into any of the existing headers for URLFetchApp  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params

```
curl \
 --cert ./<FILENAME>.p12 \
 --pass <PASSWORD> \
 -H "Authorization: orgId=<ORG_ID>" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d "<CAMPAIGN_DATA_FILE>.json" \
 -X POST "https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v1/campaigns"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in that Google Apps Script (GAS) does not support client-side SSL certificates in their [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class, which appears to be their only way to make outbound HTTP(S) requests.

Your best bet is probably to make a custom Google Apps Engine (GAE) in a language of your choice and expose an endpoint from there which when called from GAS will make a new request to your destination and provide the needed certificates. However, GAE is not free like GAS (since Google changed their cloud terms of service a couple years back), so that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks.  After hours of frustration, I've concluded this, but appeciate the confirmation.  I'm probably going to have to deploy in Python.  I'm already leveraging BigQuery and Cloud Storage, so might as well bring it all into the fold.  :)